# r david webservice sudden Transport error: 301 Error: Moved Permanently

Tags: r

I've been using RDAVIDWebService for the last few days and suddenly this morning it gives the following error.  I'm using R 3.1.1 on a Windows 7 computer although I can switch to a different computer and get the same error.
Can anyone tell me what this error means and why it appeared today and not yesterday?
Nick

> david<-DAVIDWebService$new(email="user@inst")
>   Error in .jcall(stub, "S", "authenticate", email) : 
>     org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 301 Error: Moved Permanently

Answer (score 3):

Cristóbal Fresno sent out a work-around which follows:

Work around for the new DAVID Web service configuration

1) First of all the HTTPS certificate needs Java 8 in order to run. 
Previous versions will not run due to prime size. The maximum size that Java accepts is 1024 bits. This is a known issue (see JDK-6521495).

1.1) Check your java version

```
java -version
```

```
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

If the version is 1.7.XX or earlier then you need to install Java 8. If not, go to step 2.

1.2) In windows, download and install jre or jdk 8 from oracle site

1.2) In linux follow the instructions in 
http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html 
Briefly, you need to add webupd8team repository and install the package:

```
su -echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
exit
```

2) The actual certificate used by DAVID is not signed by a recognized authority in Java brunch. Then, it must be incorporated to "cacerts" files to properly use it.
2.1) In Windows:
Download  cygwin and follow linux instructions. Usually for JRE should be installed in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\security` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\jre\lib\security` for JDK. Reboot the computer if necessary.

2.2) In Linux:
Get the certificate:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect david.ncifcrf.gov:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ncifcrf.cert
```

Check if it was properly downloaded:

```
openssl x509 -in ncifcrf.cert -text
```

Backup the cacerts file. In my case it is located in `/etc/ssl/certs/java` directory

```
sudo cp /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts cacerts.org
sudo keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -alias david -file ncifcrf.cert
```

The certificate should be added to the keystore. Now, copy the new cacerts version to the original position

```
sudo cp cacerts /etc/ssl/certs/java/
```

3) Update Java configuration in R

```
R CMD javareconf
```

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_60
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
```

4) Finally, use the new DAVID web service URL in RDAVIDWebService

```
library("RDAVIDWebService")

david<-DAVIDWebService(email="user@email", url="https://david.ncifcrf.gov/webservice/services/DAVIDWebService.DAVIDWebServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/")
david

#DAVIDWebService object to access DAVID's website. 
#User email:  user@email 
#Available Gene List/s: not submitted yet.
```